# Netty 5.0.0 closeFuture().sync() never finishing

Tags: java, netty

I'm currently writing a program in Java using Netty, where I stumbled upon the following issue:

Whenever I try to use channel#closeFuture().sync() after the "bootstrap" is done, it never finishes the task and locks the main thread forever. No exception is thrown whatsoever.

My launch code:

```
 EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
 EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
 try {
     ServerBootstrap serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
     serverBootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);
     serverBootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
     serverBootstrap.childHandler(new IOLauncher());

     this.channel = serverBootstrap.bind(8192).sync().channel();

     System.out.println("Debug; closeFuture");
     this.channel.closeFuture().sync(); // This never finishes!
     System.out.println("Debug; closeFuture done");
 } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
     workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
 }
```

Comment: FYI: The netty 5 is deprecated. You might consider migrating to Netty 4.1 before investing too much time in 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is working as intended, `closeFuture()` is a future that will complete when the channel is closed. This means that if the channel has not been closed the future will never finish and `sync()` will block indefinitely.

Comment: Does this mean I do not have to use channel#closeFuture?

Comment: How you currently use it is the intended use-case so the main thread can clean up when the server shuts down by waiting for closing. However that means some other thread must begin the shutdown at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, there was no issue at all and it was something dumb on my end.